# Converting program.cs .NET5 to .NET6

Tags: c#, .net

```
``    
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                try 
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<StoreContext>();
                    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                    await StoreContextSeed.SeedAsync(context, loggerFactory);

                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
                    var identityContext = services.GetRequiredService<AppIdentityDbContext>();
                    await identityContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
                    await AppIdentityDbContextSeed.SeedUsersAsync(userManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
                }
            }
``
```

I am trying to convert this code into .NET6. How to convert this block into .NET6? This is a course content of Neil Cummings' Udemy course

Comment: You don't need to convert the code. Just change the TargetFramework in `csproj` to `net6.0` from `net5.0` and upgrade the packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He coded this, but I am already created mine in **.net6**. I dont know how to apply this for mine. Also my project created with top level statements.

Comment: On the other hand, instead of trying to convert code without understanding it, go through the ASP.NET Core  `Getting Started` tutorials at learn.microsoft.com. This is pretty simple code - a host/app and a DbContext. It uses ASP.NET Core Identity with Individual Accounts, so the tutorial you need is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @wrongDestinations Top level statements don't impact your ability to update a .NET 5 app to .NET 6. They're optional. The template for a new .NET 6 app uses them by default, but that doesn't mean that every .NET 6 app has to use them.

Comment: @mason I selected top level statements at the beginning. So I don't know how to change them. Main problem here is that I am not able to configure this. Thanks for info...

Comment: @wrongDestinations Are you trying to migrate a .NET 5 app to .NET 6? Or are you trying to figure out how to implement or unimplement top level statements? Those are distinctly different questions. If you're trying to migrate a .NET 5 app to .NET 6 like your question states, then ignore top level statements for now.

Comment: @mason I'm trying to migrate .net5 to .net6.

Comment: Okay, so ignore top level statements. They have no bearing on converting a .NET 5 app to .NET 6. You just need to follow the directions that Panagiotis and Joaco have provided.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert anything.
Just follow this link instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

If you have installed SDK, just change csproj from

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```